# Errors Creating A Shared Library DLL for SWIG Packaged Simple Java Example (Windows)

Tags: gcc, mingw, swig

I've gone over the SWIG FAQ and dynamic module documentation and there seems to be a wide array of options when deciding on how to build the JNI shared library dll for Windows.  The [wiki](http://www.dabeaz.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?SwigFaqDLLForWindows) describes the process using very old versions of visual c++.  What is everyone using?

**I've installed MinGW and the below commands on Windows 7 and ran the below commands on the SWIG simple java example, see below:**

- C:\swig\swigwin-2.0.4\Examples\java\simple>swig -java example.i
- C:\swig\swigwin-2.0.4\Examples\java\simple>gcc -c example_wrap.c -I C:\Program F
  iles\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\include -I C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\include\win32
- C:\swig\swigwin-2.0.4\Examples\java\simple>gcc -shared example_wrap.o -o example.dll

**Last command errors out with:**

```
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `gcd'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `Foo'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `Foo'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x107): undefined reference to `Foo'
example_wrap.o:example_wrap.c:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `Foo'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've either not compiled or not linked example.c, only example_wrap.c. You need to do something like:

```
swig -java example.i
gcc -c example_wrap.c -I somepath -I someotherpath
gcc -c example.c -I somepath -I someotherpath
gcc -shared example_wrap.o example.o -o example.dll
```

Comment: that fixed the error and generated the dll, but it looks like the dll doesn't contain the proper functions as I get a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: exampleJNI.gcd(II)I when running the SWIG java simple example. Everything works on Linux, so probably some additional compilation parameter or Windwos issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: @c12 - I'm no expert on Windows DLL building issues, but I think you'll need to mark it DLLEXPORT and/or explicitly use stdcall - http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL